WKB tunneling probability calculations
I'd like to calculate the WKB tunnelling probabilities from different vibrational levels. I hope the question is not too chemical.
I have a compound which undergoes a chemical reaction. For the reaction, I calculated IRC (within density functional theory) to get the potential energy surface for further WKB approximations. Further, I approximated the points of the potential energy with polynomials for easier work (see the figure of the potential energy where the red lines are the vibrational levels of the reactant bond).

next as soon as we have the potential and the vibrational levels I embarked on the calculation of the WKB probabilities. My python code for that:
h = 6.626e-34 #J * sec
h_r = h / (2*math.pi)
c = 299792458 #m
A = 6.022e23 #Avogadro

df = pd.read_csv('E008TS_M06L.csv', delimiter = ";")


df['dE(kcal/mol)'] = (df['dE(kcal/mol)'] - min(df['dE(kcal/mol)'])) * 4.186798 * 1000 / A # converting kcal/mol into J

p = P.fit(df['Step'], df['dE(kcal/mol)'], 30)  #interpolation of the potential energy points with polynomials (yes, we are slightly overfitting this guy)

TS_E = max(df['dE(kcal/mol)']) #the highest point is our transition state. The vibrational levels cannot be higher than this


freq = 1600 #the frequency of the reactive chemical bond cm-1

E_freq = (c * 100 * freq * h) # converting the freq into J


freq_levels = []  #look for all the possible vibrations
for i in range(10):
    freq_level = (i + 0.5) * E_freq
    if freq_level <= TS_E:
        freq_levels.append(freq_level)
        plt.axhline(y=freq_level, color='r')
    else:
        break

vibr_level = freq_levels[4]  #let's calculate the WKB probability for the 5th vibrational level
roots = (p - vibr_level).roots() #finds the boundary points for further integration. Basically it is the points where the vibrational level intersects the potential energy


def k(x, poly, E_level, m):

    a = (2 * m * (poly(x) - E_level)) / (h_r ** 2)
    k = math.sqrt(a)

    return(k)

x1 = 27.90441765  #non-imaginary solutions of the roots before to find the boundaries analytically
x2 = 33.5706287


m = 1.67262192e-27 #the tunnelling proton in kg


T = quad(k, x1, x2, args=(p, vibr_level, mu))[0]

print('T: ', T)

print('P: ', math.exp(-2 * T)) #the WKB tunneling probability

plt.scatter(df['Step'], df['dE(kcal/mol)'])
plt.plot(df['Step'], p(df['Step']))

plt.show()


The problem with this calculation is that I always get tunnelling probability of 0 because the T value is always very huge. And I am very stuck to understand what is wrong here. Do I use the right dimensions of all the values (energies, reduced Planck's constant etc)?
To me it seems a bit mismatching what happens under the sqrt. The plancks constant is much bigger than the energy and mass values...
